# How to add autocomplete filter for multi value entity(USER) reference field?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

1. I have enabled [VIEWS AUTOCOMPLETE FILTER](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module.
2. I have a field : field_assigned_user which is user reference field and field settings is set to unlimited values.
3. I have created a relationship **entity reference : referenced entity field_assigned_to_user**.
4. I have added a field **field_assigned_user** which has **no relationship** and another field: **user name** having **relationship** as **entity reference : referenced entity field_assigned_to_user**.
5. What should I add in the filter criteria to get autocomplete field for field_assigned_user ?
6. For entity reference field which is not multi-valued and not an user reference field , the autocomplete field works?
7. I have referred the video link in the module [Drupal 7 Views Autocomplete Filter Tutorial](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-views-autocomplete-filter) and worked step by step. **But for the user reference field no support or help is provided**